# I installed fish shell on my computer and now I can't open the VS code terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, visual-studio-code, fish

I installed fish shell on my computer and now I can't open the VS code terminal.

When I try to open the terminal on VS code, I get the following error: "The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "/usr/bin/fish" does not exist."

I have no problems with opening the terminal from outside VS code.
And when I enter the echo **"$SHELL" command** on it, I get **/usr/bin/fish** which is exactly the path VS code isn't able to find.

How could I fix this problem?
I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: `SHELL` does not help you much here. It is a configuration problem of VS code. You would have to show how you have configured the VS terminal; but this is a question which belongs to [su], rather then stackoverflow, because it is not about programming, but about configuring an application.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) helps you tracking down the problem.

Comment: @user1934428 But it is about "software tools commonly used by programmers;", see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  The question may have other problems but not that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had this same problem. The issue is that VSC only looks for shells in /usr/bin by default. I copied the default terminal settings and updated `fish` to where `brew` installs it: `/usr/local/bin`

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
    "bash": {
        "path": "bash",
        "args": [
            "-l"
        ],
        "icon": "terminal-bash"
    },
    "zsh": {
        "path": "zsh",
        "args": [
            "-l"
        ]
    },
    "fish": {
        "path": "/usr/local/bin/fish", // overriding
        "args": [
            "-l"
        ]
    }
},
```

This should be the same for other OSes, you'll just want linux or windows instead of osx.

[image: fish running in VS Code terminal]

To get to that setting, open up your settings (cmd comma on mac or ctrl comma elsewhere), search for terminal profiles:
[image: Settings search]
and click edit in settings.json. It should take you right to the correct spot to paste in these profiles.

Comment: it's unclear what we exactly need to do in this answer. Do we need to copy paste that JSON somewhere?

Comment: VS Code uses JSON for its settings. I'll update my answer.